# How to plot spikes of neurons' data set?

Tags: excel, matplotlib, plot, graph, bar-chart

I have a dataset that you can see below. I just wanted to plot these spikes of neurons in one graph such as barchart. How can we plot and show this graph visually sensible. I am using Excel at the moment; however, Matlab, Python, R any programming language, software or tool would be helpful.

```
TIME    N1  N2  N3  N4  ALL
0       0   0   0   0   0
0.01    0   1   0   0   1
0.02    0   0   1   0   1
0.03    0   0   0   0   0
0.04    0   0   0   0   0
0.05    0   0   1   0   1
0.06    0   0   0   0   0
0.07    0   0   0   0   0
0.08    1   0   0   0   1
0.09    0   0   0   0   0
0.1     0   0   0   0   0
0.11    0   0   0   0   0
0.12    0   0   0   0   0
0.13    0   0   0   0   0
0.14    0   0   0   0   0
0.15    0   0   0   0   0
0.16    0   1   0   0   1
0.17    0   0   0   0   0
0.18    0   0   0   0   0
0.19    0   0   0   0   0
0.2     0   0   1   0   1
0.21    0   0   0   0   0
0.22    0   0   0   0   0
0.23    1   0   0   0   1
0.24    0   0   0   0   0
0.25    0   0   0   0   0
0.26    1   0   0   0   1
0.27    0   0   0   0   0
0.28    0   0   0   1   1
```